# How to change the listening port of an application

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, port

I am having an application running in my pc (Windows 7). I see that it takes a random port 49152.
How can I change the listening port of the particular application. Will I able to do this via the command line, or should I install any "exe" file for it.

Comment: If you don't mention the `application name` then all anyone can say is `check the documentation`.  A cmd prompt has no commands to change an applications ports.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the application. The application declares on which port it is listening. If you want to change that, you need to check with the documentation of that specific application. Maybe it's even hard-coded, then there's nothing you can do.

Don't forget that whoever connects to that application also needs to know the port number. That's why a listening port is very often hard-coded, because forcing the user of the client application to know the port is often not a good option.

Comment: I wanted to change the listening port midway when it is running. This is entirely from testing perspective. I donot see the application asking for user's input to run on a specified port.

Comment: The application will (if at all) have this configured trough some set of configuration option. You might be able to forcibly close the socket with an operating system tool, but that will not change it to something known. In most cases, it will just also crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds for the fact that there is no approved method for doing this.

1. The safest one is to run a proxy on the port of your choice, that forwards traffic to the dynamic port chosen by the application (some scripting will be useful for automatically determining what that is after relaunch and reconfiguring the proxy).
2. A more efficient, but more dangerous method is to hook into the application and replace the socket creation function with one that creates and also binds the socket before returning.  Since the application is designed to work with arbitrary port numbers, it is unlikely to fail... but there are always dangers associated with code injection.

Other incomplete solutions, such as configuring port assignments in the OS-level firewall, are off-topic here because they don't involve programming.